# missing values in a DataFrame with the most frequent value how to fill them?

Tags: python, html

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns: `toy` and `color`. The `color` column includes missing values.

How do I fill the missing `color` values with the most frequent `color` for that particular `toy`?

Here's the code to create a sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'toy':['car'] * 4 + ['train'] * 5 + ['ball'] * 3 + ['truck'],
    'color':['red', 'blue', 'blue', np.nan, 'green', np.nan,
             'red', 'red', np.nan, 'blue', 'red', np.nan, 'green']
    })
```

Here's the sample dataset:

```
      toy  color
0     car    red
1     car   blue
2     car   blue
3     car    NaN
4   train  green
5   train    NaN
6   train    red
7   train    red
8   train    NaN
9    ball   blue
10   ball    red
11   ball    NaN
12  truck  green
```